# What does Remv Cre stand for?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

On the <kbd>u</kbd>nit screen, some dwarves have the option `Remv Cre` enabled, some don't. What's it stand for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Removes the job that they're working on. Doesn't always work, and I haven't quite experimented with why, but it seems to be that if the dwarf is actively doing something (As in, if they're hauling the object is in their hands, or if they're in a shop and actively working, etc) you can't remove it.. but if they're on their way to do something, it immediately shifts them to No Job, and they look again for jobs to do.

[Source](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=19469&start=2800)

Comment: so that's what it does, but what is it an abbreviation for?

Comment: "Remove Creature Task"